# PHP logging approach across classes

Tags: php, logging

I've created a simple class LogHelper with a static method that I call within my application. I can call it as follows:

```
LogHelper::writeToErrorLog($config->getLogPath(), $exception);  or
LogHelper::writeToErrorLog($config->getLogPath(), $exception, $config->getLogFile);
```

The writeToErroLog method will generate a log filename if one isn't passed into it.

I have another class called Config, which basically takes an XML file and exposes the values via getters & setters. This is initialised at the start of the app & contains the log path where the error logs need to be written to.

My requirements are that I create one log file with the same filename per run of the application. When the app ends the logs, if populated, will be emailed.

My application has numerous other classes for DB, parsing data, formatting data, etc... all requiring logging at some point. The majority of my errors will come from exceptions thrown which will bubble up to the parent class, caught & handled by the LogHelper. There will be several cases where I don't want to throw exceptions and will just want to log information or errors.

My concern is that I feel like I'm constantly passing the config to every class that requires logging, which feels wrong. In addition I only want to be setting the filename for the error log once. Is there any best practice way of approaching this?

TIA

Stuff

Comment: `I create one log file with the same filename per run of the application` - how are you doing this? Using a random number or what? You should add the code if that's important for your question.

Comment: I've changed this around slightly having had time to think about it. When I first initialise my application I'm setting the log filename and saving it back to the config object, as the config object gets passed everywhere anyway. Then when I call the LogHelper I pull out the log filenanme from the config object.

Comment: I suppose my question should have been more focused on OOP, e.g. what's the best approach when an object is dependent on another object and is always required to be available? I suppose one option could be to add the config object to session?

Comment: If you want your logger to be truly agnostic you can pass the config info into it.  Zend Framework, for example, makes the config information available globally via `Zend_Registry`.  Consider my answer below, within `MyClassName::functionNameHere()` you can pass your logger the config object and the exception.  This way you're still adhering to dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)?  You wouldn't have to put the logger in every class, it would simply handle all uncaught exceptions.  You could call it within your bootstrapping process or some other application initialization spot as such:

```
set_exception_handler(array("MyClassName", "functionNameHere"));
```

Inside that function you could call `LogHelper::writeToErrorLog()`.